# How would I combine the effects of both scanning a block under a player and if they're holding an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to create a map with a "lobby" of sorts that will contain rules and more. The issue, of course, is that it's going to be relatively long, so I am trying to make a "Dash" feather that will give Speed II to those holding it, so long as they're in the actual lobby.

The problem is, I'm not getting any results with the command `execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:smooth_quartz run execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:feather",display:{Name:"\"text\":\"Dash\""}}}] run effect give @s speed 9999 2 true`, and no errors are being reported by the command block for me to debug.

I'm assuming it's probably an issue with the `{display:{Name:...}}` tag, seeing as I've always had issues with that, but I can't figure any way to change that. I've tried everything from erasing the quote escapes in `Name`'s value to changing the amount of curly brackets, but to no avail. I'm currently using 1.14 Pre-release 2.

**Edit:// I've done some more work with different commands and I've found that it is in fact a problem with at least the second half of the `execute` command; on other command blocks, I can use the block detection part (`execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:smooth_quartz run <command>`) perfectly fine.**

Comment: In 99.9% of cases "`run execute `" can just be deleted. Did you try the item detection alone? You can also throw the item on the ground and execute `/data get entity @e[type=item,sort=nearest,limit=1]` to see its NBT data.

Comment: No, I had not tried the data detection alone. Let me try that command and the item detection really quickly.

Comment: Aha! I have found the issue; apparently, for the ``{display:{Name:...}}`` section, I also have to wrap it in the ``{tag:...}`` NBT, hence why it wasn't working since there is no NBT tag "display" by itself on entity "item".

Comment: Do you, by chance, know what the pound sign in front of item/block names mean? For example; ``#minecraft:stick``. I'm trying to find a way to now remove the effect if they aren't on the block so that I don't have to wait the 1 second I changed the duration to

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and mark it as accepted if your original problem is solved, not many people read the comments. The `#` means that what follows is a tag, like "#minecraft:wool", which allows you to do "`execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ #wool` instead of one command with `execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ blue_wool`, one with `execute if block ~ ~-1 ~ green_wool` and so on. By default there is not "stick" tag, but you could add one with a data pack. For removing the effect when they are no longer on the block, just change "if" to "unless".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found out the issue was that `{display:{Name:...}}` is not standalone.** It also requires the `{tag:...}` NBT wrapping it, causing the command not to work correctly because there is no `display` tag by itself.