# How do I /give a Banner with a custom name in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to give a Banner object with a custom name of 'Keycard2'. The command I'm using is:

```
/give @p banner 1 11 {display:{Name:"Keycard2"}}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Line 1, Column 2
> Missing '}' or object member name

What am I doing wrong? Bear in mind that this is Bedrock edition, but as far as I can tell this command *should* work.

Comment: ehhh maybe. this might rather answered by (not to toot my own horn in a way) the answer to my own question; [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348953/how-would-i-combine-the-effects-of-both-scanning-a-block-under-a-player-and-if-t

Comment: at the same time, however, this is for PE, and not JE, so for all i'm aware the NBT tagging for the ``{display:{Name:...}}`` tag could be different.